# How to calcualte percentile using ANSI SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, ansi-sql

I was wondering if someone could help me with the following question for the following question and dataset.

Using only ANSI SQL assuming a relational database structure, report the bottom 3 revenue events for each site and the 75th percentile revenue for each site. The result should contain three columns (site, revenue, 75th percentile revenue). Each site should contain three rows to report the bottom 3 revenue events (the three rows would contain the same value for site and 75th percentile revenue).

```
"revenue","top","browser","platform","site"
0.00776943843268547,30.9602731291705,"safari","mobile",3
0.014156805607701,9.40058400290278,"chrome","desktop",3
0.0122753797773888,14.1199488319863,"safari","desktop",3
0.0106614882554566,29.9070545370937,"chrome","mobile",3
0.00947284187142993,19.3632264586303,"chrome","mobile",3
0.00617645820494863,20.6914934615515,"safari","mobile",4
0.00826814556437385,9.60096864605439,"chrome","mobile",4
0.00632831928919495,9.76504233515594,"chrome","mobile",2
0.00876230897437953,10.7436149034003,"chrome","mobile",2
0.0122542371574979,9.10155570695745,"safari","desktop",3
0.00734122719327969,11.9796512017936,"safari","mobile",2
0.00700850269424599,19.4384601758623,"safari","mobile",2
0.00636258609706847,23.3436268959235,"safari","mobile",2
0.0106938493186955,8.44233917110576,"safari","desktop",1
0.0104336231416902,18.2609732065633,"chrome","mobile",1
0.00609590043025647,19.8308911166086,"safari","mobile",3
0.0132940835699967,12.790110661125,"chrome","desktop",3
0.0143056180039869,14.50619738211,"chrome","desktop",4
0.00410721818995674,17.1302843168817,"safari","mobile",1
0.0139846720621539,2.28439602214985,"chrome","desktop",4
0.0139832667223559,8.64296576855354,"chrome","desktop",2
0.011386144188017,5.87860889164693,"safari","desktop",4
0.00967748879893385,4.76435336494166,"safari","desktop",3
```

Comment: That screenshot is really useless when it comes to showing example data. Can you give us something we can *use*?

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

You would use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by site order by revenue desc) as seqnum,
             percentile_cont(0.75) within group (order by revenue) over (partition by site) as revenue_75
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 3;
```

Comment: I'll give that a try thank you!!